# Access inner array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the folowing array:

```
outerarray{
            "id": "20154", 
            "from": {
              "name": "xyz", 
              "id": "10004"
            }}
```

Now **how do i access the element name**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **JSON**, decode first using `json_decode()` and then access:

```
$arr = json_decode($yourjson, true);
echo $arr['from']['name']; // xyz
```

Or

```
$arr = json_decode($yourjson);
echo $arr->from->name; // xyz
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You mus use `json_decode()`:

```
$tab = json_decode($outerarray);
echo $tab['id']; //display 20154
```